# Intersection of two arrays, retaining order in larger array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, optimization

I have a numpy array `a` of length `n`, which has the numbers 0 through `n-1` shuffled in some way. I also have a numpy array `mask` of length <= `n`, containing some subset of the elements of `a`, in a different order.

The query I want to compute is **"give me the elements of `a` that are also in `mask` in the order that they appear in a"**.

I had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42984370/2770572), but the difference was that `mask` was a boolean mask instead of a mask on the individual elements.

I've outlined and tested 4 methods below:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_test = 100
n_coverages = 10

np.random.seed(0)


def method1():
    return np.array([x for x in a if x in mask])


def method2():
    s = set(mask)
    return np.array([x for x in a if x in s])


def method3():
    return a[np.in1d(a, mask, assume_unique=True)]


def method4():
    bmask = np.full((n_samples,), False)
    bmask[mask] = True
    return a[bmask[a]]


methods = [
    ('naive membership', method1),
    ('python set', method2),
    ('in1d', method3),
    ('binary mask', method4)
]

p_space = np.linspace(0, 1, n_coverages)
for n_samples in [1000]:
    a = np.arange(n_samples)
    np.random.shuffle(a)

    for label, method in methods:
        if method == method1 and n_samples == 10000:
            continue
        times = []
        for coverage in p_space:
            mask = np.random.choice(a, size=int(n_samples * coverage), replace=False)
            time = timeit.timeit(method, number=n_test)
            times.append(time * 1e3)
        plt.plot(p_space, times, label=label)
    plt.xlabel(r'Coverage ($\frac{|\mathrm{mask}|}{|\mathrm{a}|}$)')
    plt.ylabel('Time (ms)')
    plt.title('Comparison of 1-D Intersection Methods for $n = {}$ samples'.format(n_samples))
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Which produced the following results:

[image]

So, binary mask, is, without a doubt, the fastest method of these 4 for any size of the mask.

My question is, is there a faster way?

Comment: Good question. I was playing with your code with simple test case, a = np.array([10,15,30,20,18,29]), n_samples = len(a), mask = np.array([20,18]), Method 1 works. method4 (binary mask) gives me an error "IndexError: index 20 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6".

Comment: @user1753919 The code I wrote for `method4` is only supposed to work if `a` is length `n` and **only contains numbers between 0 and n-1**, with no duplicates.

Comment: For sake of variety, a method that is faster than `in1d` but slower than `binMask` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15940459/5992438) using the `pandas.Index.get_indexer` method. Something like `a[pd.Index(mask).get_indexer(a) >= 0]` should work.

Answer (score 2):

> So, binary mask, is, without a doubt, the fastest method of these 4 for any size of the mask.
>
> My question is, is there a faster way?

I totally agree that binary mask method is the fastest one. I also don't think there could be any better ways in terms of **computation complexity** to do what you need.

Let me analyse your method time results:

1. Method running time is *T = O(|a|*|mask|)* time. Every element of *a* is checked to be present in *mask* by iterating over every its element. It gives *O(|mask|)* time per element in the worst case when element is missing in *mask*. *|a|* does not change, 
   consider it a constant. 
   *|mask| = coverage * |a|*
   *T = O(|a|<sup>2</sup> * coverage)*
   Hence a linear dependency of *coverage* in plot. Note that running time has **quadratic** dependency of *|a|*. If *|mask| ≤ |a|* and *|a| = n* then ***T = O(n<sup>2</sup>)***
2. Second method is using **set**. Set is a data-structure that performs operations of insertion/lookup in *O(log(n))*, where *n* is a number of elements in the set. `s = set(mask)` takes *O(|mask|*log(|mask|))* to complete because there are *|mask|* insertion operations.

   `x in s` is a lookup operation. So second row runs in *O(|a|*log(|mask|))*

   Overall time complexity is *O(|mask|*log(|mask|) + |a|*log(|mask|))*. If *|mask| ≤ |a|* and *|a| = n* then ***T = O(n*log(n))***. You probably observe *f(x) = log(x)* dependency on plot.
3. **in1d** runs in *O(|mask|*log(|mask|) + |a|*log(|mask|))* as well. Same ***T = O(n*log(n))*** complexity and *f(x) = log(x)* dependency on plot.
4. Time complexity is *O(|a| + |mask|)* which is ***T = O(n)*** and its the best. You observe **constant** dependency on plot. Algorithm simply iterates over *a* and *mask* arrays couple of times.

The thing is that if you have to output *n* items you will already have ***T = O(n)*** complexity. So this method 4 algorithm is optimal.

P.S. In order to observe mentioned **f(n)** dependencies you'd better vary *|a|*  and let *|mask| = 0.9*|a|*.

**EDIT:** Looks like python set indeed performs lookup/insert in O(1) using hash table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think it should necessarily be O(n). In a perfect world, it should be O(|mask|) because that's the size of what I'm outputting. Also, CPython's set implementation uses hashing, so membership checks are O(1), not O(log |mask|).

Comment: Looks like python indeed uses hash table in set.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is the bigger one.

```
def with_searchsorted(a, b):

    sb = b.argsort()
    bs = b[sb]

    sa = a.argsort()
    ia = np.arange(len(a))
    ra = np.empty_like(sa)
    ra[sa] = ia

    ac = bs.searchsorted(ia) % b.size

    return a[(bs[ac] == ia)[ra]]
```

***demo***

```
a = np.arange(10)
np.random.shuffle(a)
b = np.random.choice(a, 5, False)

print(a)
print(b)

[7 2 9 3 0 4 8 5 6 1]
[0 8 5 4 6]

print(with_searchsorted(a, b))

[0 4 8 5 6]
```

***how it works***

```
# sort b for faster searchsorting
sb = b.argsort()
bs = b[sb]

# sort a for faster searchsorting
sa = a.argsort()
# this is the sorted a... we just cheat because we know what it will be
ia = np.arange(len(a))

# construct the reverse sort look up
ra = np.empty_like(sa)
ra[sa] = ia

# perform searchsort
ac = bs.searchsorted(ia) % b.size

return a[(bs[ac] == ia)[ra]]
```

Comment: Binary mask method will be faster.

Comment: Your code seems to produce the exact same run time as `in1d`, which makes sense because they're both sorting under the hood.

Comment: This also works with other data types.  Would binary mask as well?

Comment: @michaelsnowden fun problem btw